# Adding attributes to hdf5 file

Tags: attributes, hdf5

I had this script to convert some .txt files into .hdf5. These were later used as input for another function.

I had implemented this before and everythin was running smoothly (about 2weeks ago).

```
name = "ecg.hdf5"
sampling_rate = 250;
ecg = np.genfromtxt('ecg.txt') 

hf = h5py.File(name, 'w')

# Create subgroups and add dataset
signals = hf.create_group('signals/ECG/raw')
ecg = signals.create_dataset('ecg',data = ecg)

# max and min for plot limits
ecg_max = max(ecg)
ecg_min = min(ecg)

# Add attributes
ecg.attrs.create('json','{"name": "signal0", "resolution": 16, "labels": ["I"], "units": {"signal": {"max": %f, "min": %f}, "time": {"label": "second"}}, "sampleRate": %d, "type": "/ECG/raw/ecg"}' %(ecg_max,ecg_min,sampling_rate))

hf.close()
```

As I was running it, I keep having this error and can't atribute the 'attribute'
[rro adding atribu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLsHV.png)

Any idea, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Solvet it: updating the h5py version from 2.9.0 to 2.10.0

Comment: consider posting the comment as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Solvet it: updating the h5py version from 2.9.0 to 2.10.0